# Reset Dropdown value on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling a jquery function to clear my all input fields on button click, but my requirement is when you click on clear all button it should reset my dropdown value to 1 index not to 0 index.

please let me know how i can do this.

```
function ClearAll() {
    $("#BasicCaseStatus").val(1); // This is my dropdown
}
```

This is my button.

```
<a href="#"  id="SearchClear" onclick="ClearAll()" class="clearallLink" >Clear All</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select option:eq(1)').prop('selected', 'selected')​​​;​
```

It will select the second `<option>` in the dropdownlist. Or if you wanted to do this for a particular dropdown:

```
$('#BasicCaseStatus option:eq(1)').prop('selected', 'selected')​​​;​
```

Answer (score 0):

First you want to deselect all options, then filter to the second option and select it.

```
$('a.clearallLink').on('click', function() {
    $('#BasicCaseStatus option').prop('selected', false).eq(1).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Note this works with jQuery 1.7 and onwards, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropdown_clear()
    {
        $('#dropdownlist').html(null);
    }
```

Here, I had created a function for clear the dropdown list on button click. Now, juzt copy paste the complete function and juzt call it on the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Js:

> $('span').click(function(){   $("#BasicCaseStatus").val(1); });​

Html:

```
<select id="BasicCaseStatus">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<span>Clear All</span>
```

​Link: http://jsfiddle.net/J5EE7/

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers would work If the default selected option is not the first one. The best way to achieve this is to wrap a select dropdown in `<form>` tag and call the reset() function.

```
<form id='frm'>
<select id="BasicCaseStatus">
<option>1</option>
<option selected>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<span>Clear All1 | </span>
</form>

$('span').click(function(){  
  $('form')[0].reset()
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KS6Yh/

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't write javascript code in HTML file (Remove onclick)
2. Use this js code to select second value from the list:

> $('#BasicCaseStatus').prop('selectedIndex', 1);

[A working example](http://jsfiddle.net/KS6Yh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
be it in jquery or javascript :-

$('#idname').html(null); or 
document.getElementById('#idname').selectedIndex = 0;  or 
document.getElementById('#idname').selectedIndex = -1;  

the options hasn't worked for me in dynamic dropdown list. so, i have tried

$('#idname').val("")       

try oneself for good results.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for JQuery
    $("#droplist").empty();

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant solution is this

```
$('#BasicCaseStatus option:eq(1)').prop("selected",true);
```